# How do I combine TextSymbol and a picture marker symbol in ArcGIS for javascript API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I have searched so many blogs and also ArcGIS API for JavaScript but i didn't found anything that can solve my problem.
How to combine **Text Symbol** with **Picture Marker Symbol**.?
Is there any way to combine this?

[image: This is what i want to do]

What you are looking into above picture is my requirement.

Comment: need to play with two different layers.. either text symbol need to be added on different graphic layer  or  create a different label layer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As I can understand your query you want to apply a symbol which will have a `picture marker symbol` and a `text number` (*runtime generated number*).

Well this is **impossible to combine** two symbols.

However there is a work around to achieve similar look & feel.

**Approach -**

Below are the steps to achieve this-

1. Create a feature layer and add a renderer which will have all vehicle symbol.
2. Add above layer to the map and on update End (find suitable event) add another symbol layer.
3. To create a text symbol layer first create a graphics layer and add text symbol on each location of feature layer.

It will look same as you have mentioned in picture.

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: Thanx for ur replay, i did the same in my code, but i was looking for combining this two symbol, but as u suggested i found the same that it is impossible.

Comment: glad to help..:) can you share how it look like after implementation...